# How to set data in viewpager using ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-viewpager

Here, in this viewpageradapter class is using to set data, how can I set data in viewpager. I can try to implement but I don't know how can be achieving this.I also add my PhotoviewAdater and PhotoActivity. plz solve this problem.

```
public class PhotoViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<Model_image> all_folder = new ArrayList<>();
int int_position;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public PhotoViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_image> all_folder, int int_position) {
    this.context=context;
    this.all_folder=all_folder;
    this.int_position=int_position;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return all_folder.get(int_position).getAll_imagepath().size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_photo_view_adapter, container,false);

    imageView = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.im_page);


     try {
        imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt((all_folder.get(position).getAll_imagepath().get(int_position))));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return viewLayout;
}
}
```

PhotoActivity:

```
public class PhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
int int_position;
PhotoViewAdapter photoViewAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_view);

    int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos",0);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.imagepage);
    photoViewAdapter = new PhotoViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ImageActivity.all_images, int_position);
    viewPager.setAdapter(photoViewAdapter);
}
}
```

Model_image:

```
public class Model_image {

String str_folder;
ArrayList<String> all_imagepath;

public void setStr_folder(String str_folder)
{
    this.str_folder = str_folder;
}

public void setAll_imagepath(ArrayList<String> all_imagepath)
{
    this.all_imagepath = all_imagepath;
}

public String getStr_folder()
{
    return str_folder;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAll_imagepath()
{
    return all_imagepath;
}  
}
```

[image]

Comment: post your fragment or activity code.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 imageView.setImageResource(all_folder[position]);
```

to

```
 imageView.setImageResource(all_folder.get(position));
```

all_folder is defined as an [Arraylist](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-arraylist) not as an [array](http://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java).

all_folder.get(position) returns an Model_image object.
To set the image in the imageView you need an image reference.

I dont know which image you are trying to set.

If you want to set the image from all_imagepath, try doing

```
imageView.setImageResource(all_folder.get(position).getAll_imagepath.get(<position of the required image>));
```

Comment: thank's for your replay...but not work for me....it show error:   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int

Comment: i also used try catch but in viewpager image not set

Answer (score 0):

setImageResource is used to set an image from the apk resources.

rather use      `imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(all_folder.get(position).getPath()));`

It is unclear yet from your Model_image class what an unique path can be, so you need to define a getPath() method.

Comment: No you have to implement it by yourself from your Model_image class. Currently you have ArrayList<String> all_imagepath, you need to figure out which item in the list is the one to use